# Getting firebase getDownloadURL returning

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

According to the documentation I've read `ref.getDownloadURL();` should return a link I could use in an img src.

Here is my code:
This is how I fire up firebase:

```
this.storage = app.storage();
storageRef = img => this.storage.ref(img);
```

I then call it like so:

```
const householdPics = (data, props) => {
  const ref = props.firebase.storageRef(`images/${data.profilePic}`);
  const img = ref.getDownloadURL();
  console.log(img);
}
```

data.profilePic is equal to something.jpg.
I can confirm it's in storage in firebase in a directory called

```
images/
```

The error I get in my console is:

```
"Firebase Storage: Object 'images/NULL' does not exist."
```

From firebase I can copy the path: 
gs://urlstuff.com/images
Then all my images are listed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get result of async method, you have to use `then` to get final url with access code attached to it.

ex.

```
storageRef
.getDownloadURL().then(url => { console.log(url) });
```

Here, your url will be printed at console.

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong here.

First of all, the error message is suggesting that your value of `data.profilePic` is null.  That's not valid - be sure to validate your data.

Second of all, as you can see from the API documentation, [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference.html#getdownloadurl) doesn't return the URL directly.  It's asynchronous and returns a promise that resolves when the URL is available.  This means you have to `await` it or use `then` to capture its final value, after the async work is done.